# WSO APIM 2.1.0 - how do I access HTTP POST parameters in a request

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Use case:  We have an existing production API.  We are intending to use API Manager as a pass-through mediator in order to leverage throttling and analytics on our existing API.

We have written a custom authentication handler which is loaded upstream of the default `APIAuthenticationHandler`.  This permits us to identify our users via a custom header `X-Auth-Token` as opposed to the WSO2 OAuth token - this part is working fine for authenticated routes.

Unfortunately this does not permit us to identify users accessing our authentication route, with the result that our analytics data is skewed with a lot of 'Unknown' users.

I have been attempting to work out how to access the HTTP POST parameter for our user's login in our custom Authentication handler, but I cannot for the life of me work out where Synapse stores this in the tree of classes.

Various suggestions online, such as accessing the HttpServletRequest via

```
HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) messageContext.getProperty(HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_SERVLETREQUEST);
```

do not work.

The parameters are not available as properties in the MessageContext or Axis2MessageContext objects.

The `log_in_message.xml` mediator logs a SOAP Envelope containing my desired parameters:

```
Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <xformValues>
      <api_key>*expunged*</api_key>
      <login_id>testy.user</login_id>
    </xformValues>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

but in my custom handler there is only an empty SoapEnvelope in the message context:

```
[PassThru] <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have also not been able to find an obvious mediation pattern to add to the synapse sequence for our API in order to inject this REST parameter into a property in the messagecontext.  Everything I've found online involves dynamically adding parameters to the URI.

The request in question is an HTTP 1.1 POST (content type x-www-form-encoded) and is successfully handled by the downstream service so the parameters are definitely included.

Can anyone suggest a way I can obtain the HTTP POST body or body parameters from within a java class either in the mediator tree or in a custom handler?

Thanks

Edit:  For those coming to this some time in the future, it turns out that it was as simple as invoking the mediators within my handler:

```
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) {
    ...
    // mediate
    // In order to avoid a remote registry call occurring on each invocation, we
    // directly get the extension sequences from the local registry.
    Map localRegistry = messageContext.getConfiguration().getLocalRegistry();

    // run inbound mediations
    String apiName = (String) messageContext.getProperty(RESTConstants.SYNAPSE_REST_API);
    Object sequence = localRegistry.get(apiName + "--In");
    if (sequence instanceof Mediator) {
        ((Mediator) sequence).mediate(messageContext);
    }
```

Edit 2:  A better solution is as suggeted by Bee below:

```
private String getLoginIdFromSoapEnvelope(org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2MessageContext) {
    String loginId = null;
    try {
        RelayUtils.buildMessage(axis2MessageContext);

        SOAPEnvelope envelope = axis2MessageContext.getEnvelope();
        OMElement root = envelope.getBody().getFirstElement();
        OMElement loginElement = root.getFirstChildWithName(new QName("login_id"));
        loginId = loginElement != null ? loginElement.getText() : null;
    }catch (Exception exc) {
        log.error("Unable to unmarshal via RelayUtils.buildMessage", exc);
    }
    return loginId;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
 RelayUtils.buildMessage(mc);

 String login_id = mc.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstElement()
   .getFirstChildWithName(new QName("http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse", "login_id"))
   .getText();
```

(This might need some tweaks.. - for namespace etc.)

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sample+380%3A+Writing+your+own+Custom+Mediation+in+Java

Comment: The Envelope object is an empty SOAP message within my custom handler.  I'm seeing whether I can invoke mediators as part of my handler call since it seems mediators execute after handlers within a normal request flow.  Edit:  It worked.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: I think you should build the message explicitly before accessing the body. `RelayUtils.buildMessage(mc);` Updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, this worked with a few modifications for our stack.  Thanks so much, I wouldn't have thought of this myself.

Comment: Glad to hear that.